# Como DEBUGar somente um project no Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, debug

Tenho seis projetos web C# dentro de uma *solution* no Visual Studio 2010, quando executo o *debug*, o Visual Studio lança os seis projetos de um vez, cada um deles em um processo diferente.

Será que tem como eu *debugar* apenas um projeto ou terei que colocar cada projeto dentro de uma *solution*?

Quando eu executo um projeto

[image: Serviços]

todos esses serviços são executados!

Comment: Tentou fazer um `unload` nos projetos que não vai utilizar?

Comment: Cara, coloca seu comentário como resposta para que eu possa marcá-lo!

Comment: Coloquei como resposta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer um `Unload` do projeto

Da seguinte forma:

1. Clique com o botão direito no projeto que deseja desabilitar no **Solution Explorer**
2. Clique em **Unload Project**
3. E pronto.

Caso queira reverter:

1. Botão direito no projeto que deseja reabilitar no **Solution Explorer**
2. Clique em **Reload Project**
3. E pronto.

Answer (score 2):

1. Com o botão direito na sua solução (pelo Solution Explorer);
2. escolha `Set Startup Projects`;
3. selecione o projeto que você deseja rodar em na seção `Single Startup Project`;
4. Dê o `Apply` para finalizar.

Retirado [dessa resposta](http://forums.asp.net/t/1893995.aspx?Using%20Debug%20to%20run%20only%20one%20project%20instead%20of%20all%20in%20a%20solution%20).

Comment: Cara até aí tudo bem, mas não era isso exatamente a minha dúvida. Vou editar minha pergunta para um melhor esclarecimento.

Comment: Como você ta debugando todos de uma vez? Selecione o que quer debugar "Set startup" e coloque o breakpoint onde quer que pare, então F9 até chegar lá

Answer (score 0):

1. Clique com botão direito sobre o projeto.
2. Selecione `Debug`.
3. Clique em `Start new Instance`.

Comment: Também não funcionou e iniciou os seis processos!

Answer (score 0):

Clique com o botão direito na sua solução e vá em *Configuration Manager*.

No *Configuration Manager*, altere todas as suas aplicações que você não quer executar desmarcando o check *Build* e deixe a aplicação que você quer debugar checkado.

Após isso de um clean em toda a solution e logo após um rebuild.